# How to cleanup the metadata store used for idempotent spring integration pattern

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using the idempotent receiver pattern in my spring integration flow to detect duplicate messages.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#metadata-store

In above link it says

> The value of the idempotent entry may be some expiration date, after
>   which that entry should be removed from Metadata Store by some
>   scheduled reaper.

Is there any utility/scheduler available that is provided by spring to clean up the INT_METADATA_STORE table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is no such a built-in tool for the `MetadaStore` clean up, although I believe we need to add: that's not a first time when we get a request to be able to delete (or expire) some old entries in the store. Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/projects/INT) on the matter. Looks like we need to add some extra column: `UPDATE_DATE` to be able to compare it with some time from the `expireUnusedOlderThan(long age)` callback. Something similar what we have with the `ExpirableLockRegistry`.

Since you talk about an `INT_METADATA_STORE` table, I believe you can use for time being a plain `JdbcTemplate` and some scheduled task from the Spring Framework: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling-annotation-support

Comment: Thanks will raise Jira, i am storing the jms_messageId header value in METADATA_KEY & I see timestamp in milliseconds is stored in METADATA_VALUE automatically. I changed the METADATA_VALUE column type in database to "bigint" from "varchar" and wrote a scheduler to delete the records older than one day.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem. For some reasons I store status of message in the column **metadata_value**. So it might be **started** or **finished** for now. I need to cleanup "finished" entries which were finished more than 1 day ago. So I need 1 additional column with **UPDATE_DATE** as you mentioned in the answer. Is there any workaround for now? I expect huge amount of messages so value like **finished_timestamp** doesn't look like a appropriate option.

Comment: For me "started", "finished" and if I don't have entry at all - 3 different statuse which should be handled differently.

Comment: I don't think the `MetadaStore` is an appropriate pattern for your use-case. The  "started", "finished" and so on don't sound like a metadata. I believe you need to have your own table structure and handle it yourself using the mentioned `JdbcTemplate`. Or Spring Integration JDBC Channel Adapters can help you as well. My point is let's don't abuse components for particular patterns in any other possible places!

Comment: @Artem Bilan we had to do it because sometimes messages from Google pub sub are not removed from subscription even after acknowldge(see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59391264/message-is-received-from-google-pub-sub-subscription-again-and-again-after-ackno). So I believe it is correct usage of idempotency store. It might be an option  moving entries from MetaDataStore table to the our own table with adding timestamp.

Comment: As I said: it is OK to add extra column and have it populated with a trigger. Some other processes may check the value in that column periodically and remove old rates if that. Otherwise it is not a metadata store responsibility to make assumptions combining value and something else.

Comment: 1. To add extra column do I have to remove **integration.jdbc.initialize-schema:always** ?

Comment: That’s right. Because you can’t modify scripts in the jar. Well, sounds like a separate SO thread, not comments chat

Comment: 2. How to populate extra column? metadataStore has only key and value in the interface

Comment: Let me several minutes to prepare topic

Comment: Well, wrong order for question: it uses only two columns. Everything extra can be managed externally. As I said: LAST_UPDATE can be populated with an on_update trigger on the table. All of that had to be configured on DB already

Comment: Looks like I found scenario when this approach won't work.
1. We receive new message, process it, send ack and in ack callback we fill in additional field FINISH_DATE with current timestamp
2. We receive duplicated message after callback (from the previous step) was called but before we fill in additional field FINISH_DATE. At this case app will overwrite record in the idempotency store and this message will stuck forever in the idempotency store.